# Does ParseSDK trigger some app's process recreation?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I extended Application class saving Installation and User with

```
Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("versionCode", versionCode); // version from package
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

On Parse Console's Data Browser, I see that my User object results periodically updated in the default column "*updateAt*" time. This happens every time I unlock the phone stand-by status activating wifi network connection, and it happens **even if I didnt open the app since a lot of hours**. 
Session's object results updated too.

It means that the SDK sometimes recreates by its own the app's process and infact I see it while returns active with a thread "*Parsecommandcache.runloop*":

**Questions:**

1 - 
in what other circumstances the SDK alone recreates the process , or it does so with some predefined frequency?

2 - 
is Session object updated because the User's object saving??

Comment: place to starts w docs ... http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/

Comment: there is nothing about process' recreation